# Gunicorn do not reload worker

Tags: python, web, wsgi, gunicorn, web-worker

Can I tell the Gunicorn to fail when one of the workers failed to boot? I don't want gunicorn to automatically handle and reload the worker for me, but I want it to fail not trying to launch worker again and again. Should I raise any specific exception to master process or some signal? Or I can provide a command line argument when launching master process? 
I want to implement smth like this logic in worker:

```
if cond():
    sys.exit(1)
```

and then all the gunicorn to stop without relaunching this one worker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the solution is to use [Gunicorn hooks.](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#server-hooks) There are a lot of them but for this particular case you can use `worker_int` hook.
Example of usage might be the following (simplified version, launched with `gunicorn app_module:app --config gunicorn_config.py`), content of `gunicorn_config.py`:

```
import sys

workers = 1
loglevel = 'debug'

def worker_int(worker):
    print('Exit because of worker failure')
    sys.exit(1)
```

And you worker code might be a simple Flask app for example (content of `app_module.py`:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask()
```

Other useful hooks:

- *on_exit* - before exiting gunicorn
- *pre_request* - before a worker processes the request
- *on_starting* - before the master process is initialized

That's it!